# add simple onclick js to rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple div in one of my views that I want to click to hide another element on the page. I put this in my application.js But it doesn't do anything. Did I put it in the wrong place?

```
function toggleNewPostForm {
    $('.new-post-btn').hide();
}
```

Comment: The question is: is the function (toggleNewPostForm) really triggered when clicking?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` is what you should see in your error console

Comment: I rely too much on webstorm and when i switched to sublime this happens. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `document ready` to make sure document is loaded before selecting an element from HTML and call your function inside

```
function toggleNewPostForm(){
  $('.new-post-btn').hide();
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
  toggleNewPostForm();
});
```

Comment: this will yield a syntax-error as `function <name>{<body>}()` is not a valid function-definition...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<div class="xyz">Click here!</div>
```

in javascript

```
$(".xyz").click(function(){
  $('.new-post-btn').hide();
});
```

Also check if event listener is added after document ready method? i.e

```
$(function(){
   $(".xyz").click(function(){
     $('.new-post-btn').hide();
   });
});
```

Comment: In ruby on rails, you should check against 'page:load' and 'ready' as a document-ready-Handler (because of Turbolinks...)

Comment: Sure, if someone is using turbolinks (which is by default in use since rails 4) then he should check for both page:load and ready events

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only js you have, there will be no click-behaviour. You have to tell the element, that is has to react to a click-event.

Try this in your application.js-file:

```
function toggleNewPostForm() {
    $('.new-post-btn').hide();
}

$(document).on('ready page:load', function(){
    $('.new-post-btn').on('click', function(){
        toggleNewPostForm();
    });
});
```

P.S.: As RGraham points out, you have to write the parameter-paranthesis if you define a function.

P.P.S.: In ruby on rails, you should check against 'ready' and 'page:load' as document-ready-handlers, because Ruby on Rails uses the "Turbolinks"-library by default.